# read a string using panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable string as below. I need to convert it to a dataframe and read as csv file for further processing. Please let me know how it can be achieved ?

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,1305,21:44,0,34.34,
2,1304,21:43,0,31.43,
3,1303,21:42,0,,
```

I tried below code and I got `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` error. Can some one please help ?

```
parsed_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(pd.DataFrame(string, columns=settings.COLUMNS).to_csv(index=False)))
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(pd.DataFrame(...).to_csv()))` Assuming the inner call to `pd.DataFrame` even works, why are you converting it back to CSV and back to a dataframe? I'm confused.

Comment: Also, how do you even get a string variable in a CSV format in your code? is it hard-coded? if so, why not simply saving it to disk and reading it as a proper CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

zz = """A,B,C,D,E,F
1,1305,21:44,0,34.34,
2,1304,21:43,0,31.43,
3,1303,21:42,0,,
"""

# Assuming the first column is the index,
# the first row of data contains column names
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), index_col=0, sep=',')
df.head()

#       B      C  D      E   F
# A                           
# 1  1305  21:44  0  34.34 NaN
# 2  1304  21:43  0  31.43 NaN
# 3  1303  21:42  0    NaN NaN
```